# BufferedImage not loading from png

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to load an image from a spritesheet and its been a while since I've made a 2d game, so I think I probably forgot something important. I have `res` added to the class folder and have been trying for quite a while to load it with no success. I may have loaded it into the incorrectly buildpath, but I don't think so.
Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.Dodger.graphics.ImageLoader.loadImage(ImageLoader.java:12)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.Dodger.graphics.Assets.init(Assets.java:15)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.Dodger.Dodger.init(Dodger.java:30)
    at me.xthegamerplayz.Dodger.Dodger.run(Dodger.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And here is where I am loading the image

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path){
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null; 
    }
```

And finally this is where I am loading the images:

```
    public static void init() {
    sheet = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.loadImage("/res/entities/entitySprites.png"));

    player = sheet.crop(0, 0, width, height);
    enemy = sheet.crop(1, 0, width, height);
}
```

Does anyone see a reason why it is not loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot find the resource. You can inspect the jar as it is in zip format. Most likely the path starts wrong. It also is case-sensitive.

```
sheet = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.loadImage("/entities/entitySprites.png"));
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I didn't have anything misspelled, but when I removed the `/res` it worked just fine. Thanks